# File Not Found after throws IOException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io, ioexception

I get this exception when I try to read from a file:

```
ERROR:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: newfile.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at Postal.main(Postal.java:19)
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Postal   { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception   {
        /*** Local Variables ***/
        String line;
        Scanner filescan;
        File file = new File("newfile.txt");
        filescan = new Scanner(file);
        userInfo book = new userInfo();

        /*** Loop through newfile.txt ***/
        while (filescan.hasNext())   {
          line = filescan.nextLine();
          book.addNew(line);
        }

        book.print(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are getting a runtime exception and not a compiler error. Reason for the exception, file is not found on class path.

Comment: @JunedAsan )1) yes (2) no, it is not available *in the current directory.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provide an absolute path the location where you want to create the file. And check that user has rights to create file there. One way to find the path is:

```
File f = new File("NewFile.txt");
if (!f.exists()) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to find file: " + 
        f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Try this to open file:

```
File f = new File("/path-to-file/NewFile.txt");
```

Comment: You don't need the `exists()` check. Opening the file already does that.

Comment: @EJP you should try that and see what happens. I would love to see output.

Answer (score 0):

The class `Scanner` uses a `FileInputStream` to read the content of the file.
But it can't find the file so a exception is thrown.
You are using a relative path to the file, try out an absolute one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("newfile.txt"));
```

Comment: You can load the file this way or handle errors with `file.exists()`.

Comment: It won't compile, as getClass().getResource() requires a URL, a string cannot be used.

Comment: Try this then: `File file = new File(getClass().getResource(new URL("newfile.txt")));`

Comment: This will only work if the file is in the same package as the current class, which isn't stated anywhere.